# Is there a way to add filter transitions to an Image control

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am trying to create a slideshow using Javascript and an asp.net image control. I am unable to add filter property to the image control. Any suggestions
? or is it possible to set the filter in javascript?

ex:
I want to be able to add style="filter:revealTrans(duration=2,transition=23)" to the image in ""  control.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, filters are for IE only. The result of us use [JavaScript frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913/what-javascript-library-would-you-choose-for-a-new-project-and-why) to achieve these effects..

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JQuery UI for this task

Answer (score 0):

filters work only in IE as Diodeus had mentioned. Therefore I used setTimeout property in javascript to rotate images.